# How to tell how many symbolic instructions are represented in hex machine code?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, machine-code

I have the following hex machine code:

```
25 25 A1 A1 C3 C3
```

and my goals is to convert this sequence into symbolic instructions. I know the assembler converts a series of sequential symbolic instructions into a series of sequential hex machine code instructions. I converted this hex sequence into a binary sequence:

```
1001010010010110100001101000011100001111000011
```

From this, I am trying to figure out how many instructions are present. Does anyone have any tips on how to decode this and understand how many instructions are present? I am trying to use a table of conversions such as http://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_instruction_set.pdf but I am not sure I am doing this efficiently. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Converting to binary will not help. You will need to consult opcode maps and decode the bytes to find out the instruction count.

Comment: See also other questions tagged with [tag:disassembly], beyond the ones I market as duplicates of this.  x86 machine code is byte-oriented: instructions will always start at byte boundaries.  But you have to (partially) decode an instruction to find the start of the next one.  (This is one reason high-performance hardware decoding uses so much power to decode in parallel, and pre-decode is a whole separate pipeline stage to find instruction boundaries.)